# ionic - how to use Keychain Plugin in ionic 5

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I try many ways and explore many resources but facing issues with ionic cordova Keychain plugin. is there anyone how guide me how to use it.
issues like https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keychain-plugin-not-working/192776

Comment: Show some code so we can understand more